# Heroku SQLAlchemy database does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm running a python 3.5 worker on heroku.

`self.engine = create_engine(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))`

My code works on local, passes Travis CI, but gets an error on heroku - `OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "easnjeezqhcycd" does not exist`.

`easnjeezqhcycd` is my user, not database name. As I'm not using flask's sqlalchemy, I haven't found a single person dealing with the same person

I tried destroying my addon database and created standalone postgres db on heroku - same error.

What's different about heroku's URL that SQLAlchemy doesn't accept it? Is there a way to establsih connection using psycopg2 and pass it to SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but the answer seems to be that `database_exists` and `create_database` have special case code for when the engine URL starts with `postgresql`, but if the URL starts with just `postgres`, these functions will fail.  However, SQLAlchemy in general works fine with both variants.

So the solution is to make sure the database URL starts with `postgresql://` and not `postgres://`.

Comment: Update: database_exists and create_database are now fixed to handle both prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

so I was getting the same error and after checking several times I found that I was giving a trailing space in my `DATABASE_URL`. Which was like `DATABASE_URL="url<space>"`.

After removing the space my code runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

The error was actually caused by

```
if not database_exists(self.engine.url):
    logging.info("Database not found")
    create_database(self.engine.url)
    logging.info("Database created")
```

So I just created config variable `ON_HEROKU` on Heroku and wrapped it in an `if` statement

```
if "ON_HEROKU" not in os.environ:
    if not database_exists(self.engine.url):
        logging.info("Database not found")
        create_database(self.engine.url)
        logging.info("Database created")
```